# JObject fromBody is null

Tags: json, null, .net-6.0

Why JOject is everytime null but JsonObject geting value? I created it on core 3.1 but now api work on .net6 and here it dont work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please dont use unknown objects as a parameters to the endpoint. Create a dto class instead

Comment: It must be unknown object cause its generic endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Install nuget package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson**, then in program.cs add:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

It's should work for the usage JObject as the FromBody parameter.